# why json_decode function can't decode this json string?

Tags: php, encode

I want to json_decode a string which is stored in my database. The original string is:

```
"[{\"drug_id\":\"2\",\"shop_id\":\"1\",\"drug_code\":\"HN0090840\",\"drug_name\":\"\\u5934\\u5b62\\u80f6\\u56ca\",\"manufacturer\":\"\\u4e0a\\u6d77\",\"drug_category_id\":\"3\",\"secondary_category_id\":\"5\",\"drug_type\":\"1\",\"drug_spec\":\"10M\",\"drug_unit_id\":\"6\",\"buy_price\":\"10.90\",\"retail_price\":\"30.03\",\"drug_image\":\"http:\\/\\/doctor-service.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com\\/img_161423936637.png\",\"banner_image\":\"[\\\"http:\\/\\/doctor-service.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com\\/img_161423936637.png\\\",\\\"http:\\/\\/doctor-service.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com\\/img_161423937074.png\\\"]\",\"drug_intro\":\"\",\"drug_details\":\"\\u4e00\\u9897\\u63d0\\u795e\\u9192\\u8111\",\"status\":\"1\",\"is_deleted\":\"0\",\"drug_category_name\":\"\\u63d0\\u795e\\u9192\\u8111\",\"secondary_category_name\":\"\\u6297\\u751f\\u7d20B\",\"drug_unit_name\":\"\",\"drug_type_name\":\"Rx\",\"usage_dosage\":\"\\u53e3\\u670d,1\\u65f61\\u6b21,\\u4e00\\u6b211\\u7247,\\u7528\\u836f1\\u5929\",\"usage_dosage_param\":\"\\u53e3\\u670d,1,\\u65f6,1,1,\\u7247,1,1\",\"quantity\":1}]"
```

but when I use json_decode function to decode this string, it doesn't work:

```
$drug_list = json_decode(trim($string),true);
```

so I think maybe there are backslashes in this json string, so I use stripslashes function to strip off all backslashes:

```
$drug_list = json_decode(trim(stripcslashes($string)),true);
```

and it returns nothing. so I think maybe it's encoding problem, so I print the encoding of this long json:

```
print_r(mb_detect_encoding($string));
```

and it prints "ASCII", then I tried to convert the encoding to utf-8:

```
$string = iconv("ASCII", "UTF-8", $string);
```

then I print the encoding of the return value of iconv, it is still "ASCII", which is confusing.

then I tried another convert encoding function, and it still doesn't work:

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', "ASCII");
```

I'm really confusing and could not find out a way to solve this problem now, any help or info would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the beginning and ending quotes `"` are in the post, but work fine after stripping slashes https://3v4l.org/hsY4I

Comment: It looks like it's double-encoded. Try decoding it twice. And then go fix whatever's putting it in the database like that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver no it's not working fine, look at the garbled characters in your example output, like `u4e00u9897u63d0u795eu9192u8111` instead of `一颗提神醒脑`

Comment: So I'm not knowledgeable about unicode and such but you maybe need to change the encoding before stripping slashes as that removes the \ from \u. Not sure.  My point was that it decodes, you didn't spell out the issue in the question.  You said _can't decode this json string_ which it can.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, it is work fine in json decode detector, but in my code, it doesn't work. but still thank u

Comment: @Sammitch i've tried decode it twice, still doesn't work. that's confusing

Comment: @AbraCadaver iconv and mb_convert_encoding function, both of them can't change the encoding of this string, it is still ascii

Comment: @AbraCadaver you are right, there are surplus `"` in the json the begining and ending of the json string, I delete them, it work fine. how can I make your answer as the right answer? I don't know how to do that, so I clicked all of your reply.

Comment: I don’t understand the solution or I would submit an answer